# Nginx proxy_pass with variable ip address

Tags: nginx, wowza

I am using nginx in front of wowza media server for caching video chunks. Live video is published on wowza server and wowza makes it ready to be consumed by  HLS protocol which is basically series of http GET calls which return video files. my conf looks like--

```
location /live_proxy {
            proxy_cache my_zone;
            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            proxy_cache_valid any   10m;

            proxy_pass http://wowza_server_ip:1935/live;
    }
```

The above configuration works. But here as you can see the wowza_server_ip is hardcoded into conf file. I have multiple wowza servers which will be sitting behind nginx servers and live stream can be published on any of those wowza servers. I have a external apis which tells on which of the wowza server a stream is being published. So is there a way by which i can pass on ip address with query params so that nginx can request the appropriate wowza server.

Example of url for consumption of video--
http://nginx_ip:8080/live_proxy/myStream/playlist.m3u8

Comment: after some exploration i found out that proxy_pass directive can have variables  . But i am not able to figure out how to pass these variables to nginx .http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass.

Answer (score 0):

Use upstream:

```
upstream wowza_servers {
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 1935;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 1935;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 1935;
}

location /live_proxy {
        proxy_cache my_zone;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_cache_valid any   10m;

        proxy_pass http://wowza_servers/live;
}
```

Comment: But doing this if i understand it correct will proxy to different wowza servers in round robin fashion right ?  thats not i want to achive. Since Live stream is available on only one of the wowza server for a particular stream i want to send requests for that to appropriate wowza server.  also i know the ip of wowza server where stream is present so i can send it with url something like http://...playlist.m3u8?ip=wowza_ip

Comment: Ok sorry I got it wrong. You can use sticky sessions http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky passing your target ip server in a cookie or from the URI. There is also the more flexible `learn` sticky directive but that is only available in the paid subscription. You could checkout haproxy if you really want to use the get param as the routing key with the `stick on url_param` directive.

Comment: actually i am using a rtmp module present in nginx and haproxy doesnt have an equivalent so i cant avoid using nginx. if nginx alone cant solve my problem then i will use both haproxy and nginx . But i want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @gaurav you happened to find a solution to that problem?, i am trying to do something similar using nginx.